Proof of $\frac{a-x}{((a-x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}}<\frac{a+x}{((a+x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}}$, given $0 < x < a$
I was trying to solve Problem 3.2 from David J. Griffiths' Intro to Electrodynamics (4th edition).
The problem wants us to investigate the possibility of holding a point charge in a stable equilibrium through electrostatic forces alone, by checking a particular case of holding a point charge at the body centre of a cube whose all 8 vertices also have an identical point charge fixed at them.
My first check was, taking the side length of the cube to be 2a, to displace the test charge by distance x along a line joining centres of two opposite faces, and writing the electrostatic force on it.
If released from this displaced position, whether the charge gets accelerated towards the centre or away from it comes down to the following inequality.
Desmos showed me graphically that the inequality is indeed true, but I was not able to prove it analytically.
Given that x and a are real numbers satisfying $0 < x < a$, $$\frac{a-x}{((a-x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}}<\frac{a+x}{((a+x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}}$$

Please do not use images for important parts of your question.

Thanks for writing the latex for me :)

For $0 < x < a$ is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{a-x}{((a-x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}}<\frac{a+x}{((a+x)^2+2a^2)^{3/2}} \\
&\iff \frac{(a-x)^2}{((a-x)^2+2a^2)^3}<\frac{(a+x)^2}{((a+x)^2+2a^2)^3} \\
&\iff (a+x)^2 ((a-x)^2+2a^2)^3 > (a-x)^2 ((a+x)^2+2a^2)^3 \\
&\iff 8a x^3 (7a^4 - 2 a^2 x^2 -x^4) > 0
\end{align}
$$
and that is true because $8a x^3 > 0$ and
$$
7a^4 - 2 a^2 x^2 -x^4 > 7 a^4 - 2a^4 - a^4 = 4a^4 > 0 \, .
$$
One can also (without loss of generality) assume that $a=1$, that makes the calculations a tad simpler.

Thank you so much!
